# Handle iFrame errors inside of webview

Tags: android, iframe, webview

I have a page that displays a news story, the page's content is loaded from a json response which is cached, the problem occurs when the uses is not connected to the internet and tries to access the story, the story loads correctly but the iFrame shows an `ER_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED` error.

We want to still be able to use the offline feature but if the iFrame has any error remove it from the page, is there anyway to do this ?

I've uploaded a screenshot if that helps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsmgk.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
    @Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
           // either load a new url, or show a popup to the user
           webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/custom_error.html");
    } });
```

You can decide for yourself what to do in the onReceivedError